Excel VBA Error: Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'InsertPictureInCell' of object 'Range' failed
I need help solving the following error,

"Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'InsertPictureInCell' of object 'Range' failed",

and was hoping someone here could help. I have a program in Visual Studio that is opening an Excel Template, adding data, and then running some very simple VBA code in template's Module1. The VBA code is as follows...
    Sub CellImage_Load(ImgCell, ImgPath)

        Range(ImgCell).Select
        Range(ImgCell).InsertPictureInCell (ImgPath)

    End Sub

everything works fine until the line,
"Range(ImgCell).InsertPictureInCell (ImgPath)"
which produces the referenced error.
If I debug the error and try to run the code it will continue to error, however if I manually insert one of the images and then re-test the same piece of code on a the same or a different row, it works fine. Hoping for any insight someone might be able to supply.
It is easy to replicate this error if it helps. Just create a new workbook, add a module and the below code and replace "C:\Path To Image\Image.jpg" with a valid path to an image...
Sub CellImage_Load(ImgCell, ImgPath)

    Range(ImgCell).Select
    Range(ImgCell).InsertPictureInCell ImgPath

End Sub

Sub Test()

    Module1.CellImage_Load "B16", "C:\Path To Image\Image.jpg"

End Sub

Try Running the Test() sub and it will error. Select any cell, then manually use from the ribbon Insert/Pictures/Place In Cell/This Device ... and select an image. After the image loads try the Test() sub again and it will work fine.

Side note: Range(ImgCell).InsertPictureInCell (ImgPath) shouldn't have any parentheses around ImgPath.

I got the code from recording a macro while I inserted the image and the recorded macro had parentheses around the path that's why I included them. I can try it without, though it seems weird that it work with them there as long as I have manually Inserted an image somewhere first.

There definitely shouldn't be any parentheses. The macro recorder is normally a good start, but that doesn't mean it's correct.

OK, I tested without the parentheses, and it produced the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Other suggestions would be to avoid using .Select, and to qualify  which Workbook/Worksheet that Range(ImgCell) is in/on.

I tried that first. The InserPictureInCell function only seems to work if you select the cell you are inserting into first. I try to avoid any selecting or ActiveSheet reference whenever possible.

Using Excel 365 here. Your example code worked perfectly for me, no errors.

That's odd. I'm also using 365 and every time I do the steps above I get the error, unless i've inserted manually first.

Similar: https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/1b3tocm/insertpictureincell_in_vba_gets_runtime_error/

Thanks, that is the exact same situation and problem. Too bad they didn't have a solution.

@PopeScooby I believe the ÌnsertPictureInCell` method posts the image into the selected cell regardless of the range qualification. I think this is one of those cases where the cell must be selected.

That Reddit post and others, like this one here (caution ads!), list some of the common reasons for this error.
Yet none of them mention the reason that I think is most common: this runtime error is thrown if a different workbook is active.
That's what my money would be on.
You have to activate the target workbook before selecting the target sheet and cell. You might also activate your target sheet in case it's on a different one (and make sure it's visible and unprotect it if cell selection isn't allowed - any of these will cause an error on selection) I'd also qualify your range so that you have a bit more security in which workbook is being called (even though you've just activated the one you want). Your test routine could be modified as follows:
Public Sub Test(cellAddress As String, imagePath As String)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    With Sheet1 'or whichever sheet codename you want to use.
        .Activate ' make visible and unprotect if necssary.
        With .Range(cellAddress)
            .Select
            .InsertPictureInCell imagePath
        End With
    End With
End Sub

I don't know if this will solve your issue, but I'd certainly start here.
